# How to handle dynamic object import from a JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I would like to create a way for users to import any named object from a JavaScript module, just like Python's module level `__getattr__` (3.7+).

I'm now using a `Proxy` object to provide traps for non existent properties on other objects and I want to create similar behavior on modules.

What I've tried so far:

```js
// mymodule.js
export default new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, property) {
    if (property in target) {
      return target[property];
    }

    // Returning a simple function just for testing
    return function() {
      console.log('Hello World');
    }
  }
});
```

Importing this `Proxy` object works just fine because it's the `default` export:

```js
import p from './mymodule.js';

// Then I can get the hello function by using any name
p.hello(); // -> Hello World
p.anythingWorks(); // -> Hello World
```

But trying to import a single export that doesn't exist:

```js
import { hello } from './mymodule.js';
```

Causes an error `The requested module './mymodule.js' does not provide an export named 'hello'` which is true, but I hoped that it'll be handled by the `get` trap, I don't know much about how the modules work internally.

How would implement this functionality? How can I make this `Proxy` object handle module imports?

I'm using the latest Node.js version 13.5.0 if that matters.

Comment: This is not possible (without falling back to commonjs via a transpiler, and messing with the `module.exports` object). Any `import`ed name **must** be explicitly declared somewhere. Notice that (unlike in Python) the exports are not an object (that you could proxy), they are a table of aliases for declared variables.

Comment: @Bergi thank you, I have tried your suugestion and assigned the `Proxy` object to `module.exports` and it works, but if I transpile my current ES modules code to CommonJS is this feature going to be added later to ES modules?

Comment: No, this hack is not a feature, it will hardly ever become part of the ES module standard. Statically analyzable exports are a core quality of ES6 modules, making them dynamic is not going to happen.